# Can an untilted perspective of an object be obtained from a 2D image of a tilted object using angular transformations?

Tags: image-processing, geometry

I'm trying to make a height estimation algorithm that works in tandem with a bounding box object detector. The object detector can recognise the objects in images taken at pitch/yaw angular offsets.

Given these pitch and yaw offset angles are known, is it possible to apply a transformation on the object bounding box to obtain the box's equivalent dimensions in an un-tilted perspective, which would subsequently be used by a height estimation algorithm?

Comment: Hi brentnallt. I hope you can post some example images indicating clearly which length do you want to measure ?